# jQuery Fancybox - funny errors and no popup window

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am getting "is null" errors on a jQuery fancybox install [here](http://www.theideapeople.com/charlotte-web-design)

Here is the jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.video").fancybox({
            'zoomOpacity'           : true,
            'overlayShow'           : false,
            'zoomSpeedIn'           : 500,
            'zoomSpeedOut'          : 500
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the html portion:

```
<a class="video" href="#testube"><img src="images/video.jpg" alt="Idea People Video" /></a>

<div style="display:none" id="testube">
        <object width="560" height="340">
            <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/9VUhmErOxwk&hl=en_US&fs=1&rel=0"></param>
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
            <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/9VUhmErOxwk&hl=en_US&fs=1&rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="560" height="340"></embed>
        </object>
</div>
```

Would appreciate some help figuring out why I get the error and no popup video.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I am struggling with something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178628/detecting-dom-ready-state-within-an-iframe-jquery

Comment: Hi Sonny. I have not found a super useful solution yet. apparently Prototype and jQuery don't play together very well. I ended up removing the Prototype stuff and just sticking with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a conflict with $ on the page since prototype is being included on the page as well, this will work since $ is taken over by prototype:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("a.video").fancybox({
        'zoomOpacity'           : true,
        'overlayShow'           : false,
        'zoomSpeedIn'           : 500,
        'zoomSpeedOut'          : 500
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Nick, I made the change but it still does not work properly. Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: @fmz: I updated the above (though the previous worked for me, at least in FF 3.6)...try that code, it now replaces all $ references.

Comment: Hi Nick. Alas no go. I am going to try a Prototype version to see if I can avoid the conflict - it is always more complex to fix someone else 's code. Thanks for the help. I'll follow up after I get it going.