# jQuery FancyBox Iframe - Using $(document).ready within the fancybox?

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox to load a form as an Iframe, but for some reason my `$(document).ready(function ()` isn't working for some reason.

Any idea why?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using, and is jquery included in the page that iframe's loading?

Comment: Please show some code. Also, are you sure you are not getting any errors in the error console?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your code, I'm going to take a wild guess (but it's something I've seen quite a bit of)...

Are you trying to do some interaction with the host page from within the iFrame (and the content in the iFrame is coming from a different domain)? If so, that is considered a cross-site scripting security issue and most modern browsers will block the calls.

Check/Enable Javascript errors (or look at the Javascript console if your browser has one) and see if you're getting any specific error messages.

Answer (score 0):

See [Detecting DOM Ready State Within an iFrame (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178628/detecting-dom-ready-state-within-an-iframe-jquery).