# does reaching the end of an html page equal to a "page loaded"?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, load

To test if a page is loaded, it is possible to add a "load" event listener on the window:
`window.addEventListener ("load", function(){});`

But in certain case, this event is never fired even if everything is loaded: imagine that you want to execute some JS when the page is loaded, but this page is not get as usual. It is loaded into an iframe without setting its "src" property but by doing
`iframe.contentWindow.document.write ("<!DOCTYPE html><html>...</html>");`
In this case, the "load" event is not thrown.

But whatever, inside this page, it is still necessary to be able to known when the page is like "loaded", to begin some js stuff.

Can i assume that if the end of the html is reached, then the page is loaded? If the answer si "yes", then starting the JS in a `<script>`tag at the end of the page would do the trick...

In other words: in a normal load workflow (by setting the "src" attribute) does some other "init" processes still asynchronously run at the end of the page (like a css engine init process), and the "load" event is fired only when all of these processes terminate? are these processes also present when loading a page by using `document.write`?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting DOM Ready State Within an iFrame (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178628/detecting-dom-ready-state-within-an-iframe-jquery)

Comment: Well, the [Detecting DOM Ready State Within an iFrame (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178628/detecting-dom-ready-state-within-an-iframe-jquery) does not exactly cover my question... But whatever it helps me: adding a script just before the `</body>` tag would not do the trick: the DOM is ready but some other "init" stuff are still running (assets loading, etc.). So the answer is: **"reaching the end of the DOM is not equal to a page load. The "load" event comes later the DOM creation** (and will not be fired when using `document.write`).

Comment: Yes, i comment it and mark it as the right answer. Whatever, thanks. I have something against me having forgotten to close an opened document... tiredness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to the question in the header is no.

Practically [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) fires when `</body>` is met, but for example some images can still be under loading. [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/load) fires after all the content and resources (like images and contents of iframes) of the page have been loaded.

When you write to any document using `document.write()` after that page has been parsed, `write()` implicitely opens the document, but it doesn't close it. "Ready" events can't be fired while the document is open. Hence after `document.write()`(s) you've to close the document manually:

```
document.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right. Closing the document make the "load" event being fired !

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery it's as easy as this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

That event triggers once the DOM is ready which is most probably sufficient for starting DOM-Manipulations via JS. The onload event on the other hand triggers after all the assets to the page like images are loaded as well and can therefore take a little longer to be triggered.